# Save emails and passwords from unautorizades users Laravel 5

Tags: validation, laravel, email, security, laravel-5

I created the login using php artisan make:auth
I read I have to override AuthController.php but , I want to override Login() function and I got some errors.

I wanted modify this file, but I read I can't do.

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

So , I wanted to override  AuthController.php which use AuthenticatesUsers.php but I couldn't override it.

In short words , I would like to save emails and passwords from unautorizades users , but where can I get that fields ,. I created a model like this.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccessHistory extends Model
{
    //
     protected $fillable = [
        'usuario_id', 'password','date_access','correct',
    ];
}
```

How can I get that fields,before to login ?
I would like to ask other question. I don't know if I have to create other thread , but there is in the same way.
I would like to have password which expires 30 days after, and change it . How can I do that?

Comment: for the second question , just add pasword statys field 1=active , 0= expiered  , and then compare the updated at field with current time, if <30 it stays active, else password status expiers

Comment: So you are wanting to save the email addresses and passwords of unauthorised users? How will you get this information? Why don't you just ask them to register instead as you would get the information that way...

Comment: Thank you ,  Yes ,I thought that , but the problem is when I change for example the email or  username ,They will change update_at field in the table. I don't know if there is a way using laravel security or something like that. I have to add a new field update_password_at in user table if there's not other way.

Comment: @James Thanks you for your comment. It will be a intranet  system . So I have to save all login activity, because no one can add new users except the administrator. We can find an intruder in this way.

Comment: Then why not just set the `auth` middleware on all of your routes so that all users have to be logged in to use the system? And then you could either use a package or build your own method to log every route loaded against the user.

Comment: Well , I need where Laravel do the comparation between the fields and the model/database . There is the moment where I can save as a model with the date. I have worked in laravel for few weeks , sorry if I don't understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

The auth layer fires events when a login is attempted. If you wanted to record the username and password used as part of a failed login then you could do the following.

In your `EventServiceProvider` `boot` method add:

```
$dispatcher->listen('auth.attempt', function ($credentials, $remember, $login) {
    AccessHistory::create([
        'email' => $credentials['email'], 
        'password' => $credentials['password']
    ]);
});
```

Note that in this example I assume that you are using email in the login form. There are also alternative options to handling events using the EventServiceProvider.

You can read more about the events fired from the auth layer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#events).